# We could not associate your app with the selected Domain

Tags: android-app-indexing

When I make google app indexing with the web domain its work successful but same app re-associate with the same domain from another Computer shows error.

> We could not associate your app with the selected Domain please make
>   sure the digital asset link file is uploaded to correct domain

How to fix it?

I'm also have replaced assetlinks.json with new one.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to configure your app in the console (under settings) and add the SHA256 hash.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/-cUawqrLBuw